# Alpha Decay or Fission

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

In a quiz contest, I came across the following question:
What is the term used to describe the splitting of a heavy nucleus into two lighter nuclei?
Two options provided were: a) Alpha Decay b) Fission. Apparently, the correct answer is b) Fission. But even in Alpha Decay, a Helium nucleus is formed (i.e., the alpha particle), along with the daughter nucleus; both of them are obviously lighter than the parent nucleus, and so, doesn't this also fit the required criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alpha decay is treated as a special case and is usually not included in the term "fission", although it arguably is a fission (especially in the case of light elements where the alpha can represent an appreciable fraction of the original mass).

So, for the purposes of a quiz you want "fission".

Comment: Even Carbon-nucleus is emmited in some decays. Then it would be about the **speed** of the thing.

Answer (score -3):

The key of the question is: "heavy nucleus into two lighter nuclei".

Alpha decay produces only one nuclei - a Helium nucleus.

Fission is the right answer.

Comment: What about the daughter nucleus?